# how to get a image from large video using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

My code run very well. But this process is tiring my processor. I have 1000+ videos to make it

Is there anyone to have more useful code?

```
import cv2
 
video = cv2.VideoCapture("E:/videos/example1.mp4")
length = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
video.get(cv2.CAP_INTELPERC_IMAGE_GENERATOR)
print( length )
i=0
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
 
    if not ret:
        break
    i+=1
    if length/50 < i:
        cv2.imwrite('res'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)
        break
 
video.release()
```

Comment: What is the goal here ? capture every 50th frame ?

Comment: I took pictures from the beginning to recognize the videos. I have 1500+ videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found new code

```
import cv2

#taking the input
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('E:/videos/examples1.mp4')

#setting the time
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,137000)   

success,image = video_capture.read()

if success:
    cv2.imwrite("frame137sec.jpg", image)     

video_capture.release()
```